# Machine learning dataset label depending on more than one row

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset

I'm trying to label my dataset which consists of two columns representing power readings from two machines against time every second. If an activity happens at the first machine and then the second one I will have to label that as 1 or 2 if any other case occur it should be 0. I want to label this dataset in a way in which a machine learning algorithm would notice that the first machine power reading activity should occur before the second but the algorithm just predicts all the labels as zeros which deceives me by a very high results such as 99% accuracy because I label them as 1 or 2 after the activity in the second machine is over and in only one row so the number of 1s and 2s in the label is very low compared to that of the zeros. Is there any good way to label this dataset ?

Comment: Which type of learning do you use?

Comment: decision trees and I also used svm

Comment: It seems that you want to use a supervised learning algorithm for this kind of problem. I don't think it's the best choice, I think you really want a detector and not a classifier. If you know an activity has to happen on machine 1 before machine 2, you can probably write a rule-based detector. If you know how the activity should happen, but you're not able to model it in a set of rules. You can try to use an anomaly detection algorithm.

Comment: Your task seems to be sequence model and I think you can not do that using decision trees or svm

Comment: This task needs sequence model as I think or I understood task incorrectly

Comment: ok, but the original question is how am I supposed to label them regardless of the learning type